# Maven Build error TOOLS.JAR NOT FOUND IN JRE

Tags: maven, build

I am getting this problem while building maven project .. please help me out..

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) on project Subs_Engine: Fatal error compiling: tools.jar not found: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\..\lib\tools.jar -> [Help 1]
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're getting this in eclipse make sure that Eclipse is pointing to a JDK and **Not** a JRE.

In Eclipse navigate to Window->Preferences->Java->Installed JRES- Add... Standard VM and point Directory... to a JDK.  You'll obviously need to install a JDK if you have not done so.

Answer (score 12):

I think you need to point JAVA_HOME to a JDK not just a JRE. The JRE is the java runtime environment while the JDK is for development and will contain the compiler and libs required.

Answer (score 1):

Your build path is pointing to the wrong JRE directory/folder. You need to select the JRE folder which is present inside the JDK

Steps to change

1. Go to eclipse- click on windows(Last second option)
2. Click on Preferences- Search for Installed JREs
3. click on add -> select standard VM- click next
4. Under JRE Home - click directory -< Navigate to the location in your system where Java is downloaded

for eg C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\jre
5. Select Finish-> check the folder selected-> apply -> apply and close

Clean your project and compile it. It should work fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Tried all that was mentioned in the above solutions but didn't work. Finally, after scratching up my head for hours, I could do it with below actions:

*windows > preferences > installed jres > click edit on the selected jre/jdk > add external jar > add in tools.jar*

Hope this helps you save a lot of time. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I faced that error after update my java version from **1.8.0_201** to **1.8.0_221**. In the new folder the tools.jar was missing. I found tools.jar file on previous version under "**C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_201\lib**" directory(Assuming java is installed under C:\Program Files). I just copied the file and pasted on "**C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_221\lib**". The tools.jar file also can be found on "**C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\lib**"(version that I installed) directory. It solved my problems. Not quite sure as it is the perfect solution but it works every time. Hopefully same technique would work for other OS too.